# How to turn BB style string to html markups? e.g. [h1]Sample Heading[/h2] or [a href="#link"]Sample Link[/a]

Tags: javascript, jquery, bbcode

As the title says, I want to implement a BBcode style string and be able to turn that to valid html markup!

I know it's silly to do something like this in the frontend but unfortunately I have no other choice :(

Basically I'm working with an ASAP.net CMS which doesn't have much flexiblity nor features to handle such task, again I don't have access to the backend codes in any way!!!

All I have access to is some generated html source codes etc.

Basically I have a photogallery features which only provides to upload image along with text-based caption, any attempts for putting html markup as for the caption, the website breaks... but I want to use

and  as for the caption...

So what I could do for the moment to use BBcode style type of string and convert that to valid html markup using JavaScript!

I already implemented a [BR] for 
 and it works, but I want to do it for the ones that has opening and closing tags just like h1 and a example that I mentioned above!!!

```
                    // ASSIGNING IMAGE
                    var image = $('img'),

                    // CAPTION
                    title = img.attr('src');

                    // IF TITLE IS NOT UNDEFINED OR NOT EMPTY
                    if(typeof title != 'undefined'){
                        var array = title.split('[BR]');
                        $('#content .slider ul.caption').append('<li value="' + index + '"></li>');
                        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            var data = array[i];
                            if( i != 0) {
                                data = '<span class="element-' + i + '">' + array[i] + '</span>';
                            }
                            $('#content .slider ul.caption > li').eq(index).append(data);
                        }
                    }
```

Many thanks :)
I appreciate any help, cheers

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? https://gist.github.com/neo22s/2584465

Comment: I know that one mate, but that's in PHP and as I said I don't have access to the back-end code, neither could code any server side programming language! Must be in JavaScript! Besides, the CMS it's based on an ASP .NET and not PHP! Cheers

Comment: https://github.com/wGEric/phpBB-BBCode-Javascript-Parser

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'll give it a try although I'm pretty sure it will work, again thanks for the time, I really appreciate it, cheers